# Validating structure of Json object in WCF Rest Service

Tags: json, rest, validation, wcf, post

I have written a WCF Rest Service, where in POST method Json Object is received as StudentDetails. Now i want to validate its structure that it should not contain extra fields/information than the specified fields.
Below is my service(ServiceContract)

```
namespace RestService
{

[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestService
{
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/SaveStudent", RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string SaveStudent(StudentDetails studentDetails);
}

[Serializable]
public class WebServiceDictionary : ISerializable
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Entries { get; }

    public WebServiceDictionary()
    {
        Entries = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    public WebServiceDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Entries = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var entry in info)
            Entries.Add(entry.Name, entry.Value.ToString());
    }
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach (var entry in Entries)
            info.AddValue(entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class StudentDetails
{

    [DataMember]
    public WebServiceDictionary StudentDetail { get; set; }
}
}
```

This is implementation of Service

```
namespace RestService
{

public class RestService : IRestService
{

    public string SaveStudent(StudentDetails studentDetails)
    {
        SqlHelper sql = new SqlHelper();
        sql.OpenConnection();

        WebServiceDictionary student = studentDetails.StudentDetail;



        if (student.Entries.Keys.Count != 3)
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return null;
        }
        sql.SaveJson(student.Entries["Name"], student.Entries["Address"], int.Parse(student.Entries["Grade"]));
        sql.CloseConnection();

        return "Passed";
    }
}
}
```

So the Structure of Json should be

```
{
"StudentDetail" : 
{
    "Name" : "ABC", "Address" : "ABC", "Grade":"10"
}
}
```

I have put checks for not letting the request accepted when there is/are some fields are missing and it is working fine. Now i want that when Json data contains one or more extra information, the request should fail(BadRequest). For example if Json object is:

```
{
"StudentDetail" : 
{
    "Name" : "ABC", "Address" : "ABC", "Grade":"10", "Extra" : "Item"
}
}
```

As Extra item is present so it should fail(BadRequest). 
And also

```
{
"StudentDetail" : 
{
    "Name" : "ABC", "Address" : "ABC", "Grade":"10"
},
"New" : { "key" : "value" }

}
```

As extra "New" item is introduced so it should fail(BadRequest).

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide possible solution or some links to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately you cant do this with wcf. in web api you simply can use dynamic object and validate the input. but in wcf you have to use an object like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class WebServiceDictionary : ISerializable
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Entries { get; }

    public WebServiceDictionary()
    {
        Entries = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    public WebServiceDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Entries = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var entry in info)
            Entries.Add(entry.Name, entry.Value.ToString());
    }
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach (var entry in Entries)
            info.AddValue(entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
}
```

then your input will be like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class StudentDetails
{

    [DataMember]
    public WebServiceDictionar StudentDetail { get; set; }
}
}
```

now you can access to the `StudentDetail` like this:

```
StudentDetail.Entries[Name]
```

and then validate it.
at first you can get all the keys in your dictionary like this:

```
var keys=Entries.Keys;
```

then you can validate them like this:

```
if(keys.length!=3)
//its not valid
if(!keys.contain("Address"))
//its not valid
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks @David for your response but i couldn't understand much how to integrate it with my code. Could you please provide more details so that i can make use of it? Also how to access the extra fields from 'StudentDetail.Entries[Name]' because i don't know the Name of extra fields that might be present in the input?

Comment: you are welcome dear @learner. which part of the code you didn't understand? Entries is a simple dictionary. you can access to its keys with keys. i updates my answer. please take look at it.

Comment: I tried it and only able to get the first Inner Json object "StudentDetail" and validate it, but couldn't find extra Inner Jsob object "New". I updated my question by implementing your piece of code. Please tell me what i'm missing in code and how can i find other inner Jsob objects.